# How to concat two strings in JPQL with MS SQL

Tags: jpa, sql-server-2008-r2, jpql

I am trying to update a column (in an MS SQL table) which holds very long strings (text data type) appending it with a string from my application using JPQL. But the following query fails:

```
UPDATE entity e SET e.longText = CONCAT(e.longText, :textToAppend) WHERE e.id = :id
```

with message

```
The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the add operator.
```

The problem is that we need to also support other DBS than MS SQL database and DBS-specific queries are out of question (at least if there is another way).

With this query I was trying to bypass querying for the whole long text and concatenating it in the app and updating it back, so it's not slow (the query is called quite often).

Can I somehow append a string to a very long text column without doing it manually in the app and so it works in MS SQL? (I know there is no cast support in JPQL, sadly)

Using JPA with Hibernate.

Comment: Why are you using `TEXT`? You know that data type was deprecated almost 10 years ago right?

Comment: @aaron-bertrand I know, but it is what JPA maps to a \@Lob String property (and again it must be compatible with other DBMS, so I can't specify DBS-specific data types)

Comment: I'm not saying change anything in your code, I'm saying you're getting that error message back from SQL Server because *it* knows it can't append your string to a TEXT column. But if the underlying data type for SQL Server is (N)VARCHAR(MAX), the operation should succeed, and this doesn't change anything about how you handle this in any other DBMS.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I know what the problem is. It is the solution I don't seem to understand. Sorry, still not sure what you suggest. For the SQL Server the parameter is of type nvarchar, but the column is of type text created by the hbm2ddl. Both I have no control over.

Comment: You can't alter the table after it's been created? Why not? With these limitations I would be looking for a different tool. Software in 2013 shouldn't be forcing you to use deprecated and problematic data types that haven't been needed since SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I can, but it just makes it more complex, I (we) have to keep in mind that for MS SQL there is a need to replace the data type generated by hbm2ddl. Makes it more vulnerable to bugs in future refactoring of entities. However, I maybe have found a solution using an inherited MS SQL dialect which overrides the data type mapping. Will try now. Thanks for comments.

Comment: File a bug with whoever creates this thing, they really have no excuse to be using TEXT anymore - even if they still support SQL Server 2000, their DDL should be able to fork.

Comment: As it turns out, there was one other dialect for newer versions of SQL Server which maps the `@Lob String` correctly to nvarchar(max). Solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was using old hibernate dialect. There is a dialect for SQL Server 2008 (`org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect`) which maps `@Lob String` properties correctly.